# SendInput (C++) is not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The return value is 4 and I'm running Visual Studio in administrative mode so permissions should be ok. I don't see anything typed out though. Any help? I'm using Windows 7 x64.

```
INPUT input[4];

input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[0].ki.wVk = 0;
input[0].ki.wScan = 'a';
input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
input[0].ki.time = 0;
input[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[1].ki.wVk = 0;
input[1].ki.wScan = 'a';
input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
input[1].ki.time = 0;
input[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

input[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[2].ki.wVk = 0;
input[2].ki.wScan = 'a';
input[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
input[2].ki.time = 0;
input[2].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

input[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[3].ki.wVk = 0;
input[3].ki.wScan = 'a';
input[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
input[3].ki.time = 0;
input[3].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

int retval = SendInput(4, input, sizeof(INPUT));
if(retval > 0)
{
  wxLogDebug("SendInput sent %i", retval);
}
else
{
  wxLogError("Unable to send input commands. Error is: %i", GetLastError());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send both KeyDown and KeyUp events for each key.
To send a KeyUp event, set `dwFlags` to `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`.

Also, you need to use `wVk` instead of `wScan`. (`wScan` is only used with `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`)

Comment: I changed the flag to KEYEVENTF_UNICODE and it worked with the scancode. The up event isn't required actually though the example I showed had it.

Answer (score 3):

Just to spell it out for whomever comes across this. I **added** KEYEVENTF_UNICODE and **removed** KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE.

> KEYEVENTF_UNICODE 0x0004 If specified,
>   the system synthesizes a VK_PACKET
>   keystroke. The wVk parameter must be
>   zero. This flag can only be combined
>   with the KEYEVENTF_KEYUP flag. For
>   more information, see the Remarks
>   section.

-[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

The sample should output "aa".

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    INPUT input[4]; 

    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
    input[0].ki.wVk = 0; 
    input[0].ki.wScan = L'a'; 
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE ; 
    input[0].ki.time = 0; 
    input[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

    input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
    input[1].ki.wVk = 0; 
    input[1].ki.wScan = L'a'; 
    input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP  | KEYEVENTF_UNICODE ; 
    input[1].ki.time = 0; 
    input[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

    input[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
    input[2].ki.wVk = 0; 
    input[2].ki.wScan = L'a'; 
    input[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE ; 
    input[2].ki.time = 0; 
    input[2].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

    input[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; 
    input[3].ki.wVk = 0; 
    input[3].ki.wScan = L'a'; 
    input[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_UNICODE ; 
    input[3].ki.time = 0; 
    input[3].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

     SetConsoleTitle(L"TESTING");
     ShowWindow(FindWindow(NULL, L"TESTING"),SW_MINIMIZE );

    int retval = SendInput(4, input, sizeof(INPUT)); 
    if(retval > 0) 
    { 
      _tprintf(_T("SendInput sent %i"), retval); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      _tprintf(_T("Unable to send input commands. Error is: %i"), GetLastError()); 
    } 



    return 0;
}
```